# SQL Azure retry logic using EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, enterprise-library

Trying to implement a retry logic in a correct way, but couldn't find any good sample on how to properly leverage EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.
So far I found two samples:

First - using `ReliableSqlConnection` & `conn.Open(retryPolicy)`

```
var retryStrategy = new Incremental(3, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
{
    using (var conn = new ReliableSqlConnection(datasetConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open(retryPolicy);

        using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = insertToParameters;
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            conn.ExecuteCommand(command);
        }
    }
});
```

and second - without the ReliableSqlConnection:

```
var retryStrategy = new Incremental(3, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(datasetConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = insertToParameters;
            command.CommandTimeout = 0;
            conn.ExecuteCommand(command);
        }
    }
});
```

So few questions:

1. which one is better and why?
2. Is the external `retryPolicy.ExecuteAction` really needed - in older samples I see people retrying only individual actions, like `OpenConnectionWithRetries`, `ExecuteCommandWithRetries`, etc, but not the whole thing - I wonder if that is possible that the connection could potentially be closed between those retries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

With newer transient error handling block, use SqlConnection with the provided extension methods, such as OpenWithRetry, etc.

Use retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => {...}) whenever there is no support for the retry in the API, such as SqlBulkCopy, filling the dataset table, async methods etc. Make sure to re-open connection in the retry block. You still can use the SqlConnection with retry-able extension methods inside the retry block.

UPDATE: edited to cause less confusion

Answer (score 1):

The best pattern to use is RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => .     Wrap your database interactions into an ExecuteAction() lambda and treat that as a unit of work.   This maintains the highest level of compatibility with ADO.Net's APIs.  It also allows you to work with the new Async methods in ADO.Net.

The ReliableSQLConnection is primarily offered for backward compatibility.

Comment: I wouldn't call ReliableSqlConnection as obsolete - it has its own usage with retry-able calls, where you don't have to re-open connection by yourself.